# Get all posts using xmlrpc in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

Am new to wordpress,how can i fetch a blogpost from database using xmlrpc in wordpress?please show me some references also..

my code:

```
$o = WordPress:::XMLRPC->new({
username => 'abc',
password => 'abcd',
proxy => 'http://localhost/folder/xmlrpc.php',
   });
$post = $o->getPost(7);
  echo  $post->{title}; 
?>
```

The above code i used ,but not working..please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the `IXR_Client` class :

```
$client = new IXR_Client('http://url/xmlrpc.php');
```

Then you have to write your method or use one off the remote server (wp-includes/class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php) and call it as follow :

```
if ( !$client->query('nameYouWant.methodeName') ){
    echo('Error occured while executing methodeNamemethod : ' 
         . $client->getErrorCode().":".$client->getErrorMessage()
   );
}
$results = $client->getResponse();
```